# Do I need duplicate object checking in each validator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, refactoring

Do I really need to check `if shift` in my custom validator when I have `validates :shift, presence: true`

Can I refactor it somehow?

```
class ShiftLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shift
  validates :shift, presence: true
  validate  :check_limit

  def check_limit
    if shift
      shift_logs = ShiftLog.by_shift(shift)
      if shift_logs.count >= self.shift.limit
        errors.add(:shift_id, "Exceeded limit")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need it so it doesn't crush when shift has not been assigned. The fact you have another validation doesn't change the fact, that it may fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need to check it again. It looks fine except you can write one liner conditions:

```
 def check_limit
   shift_logs = ShiftLog.by_shift(shift)
   errors.add(:shift_id, "Exceeded limit")  if shift_logs.count >= self.shift.limit
 end
```

Comment: If you validate object with no shift, this validation will throw an exception. If shift is not assigned, this validation should pass without exception.